# How can use different backing bean properties inside text of an EL expression?

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I am trying to display a different message for type of user logged in but getting parsing exceptions

```
<ui:define name="header">
        <ui:param name="userParam" value="#{bean.user.firstName} - #{bean.user.lastName}" />    
        <p:panel id="headerPanel"
            header="#{bean.adminUser ? 'Welcome Power User' userParam : bean.normalUser ? 'Welcome User' userParam :'Welcome to sytem'}"/>
    </ui:define>
```

**This is the exception**

```
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "?" at line 1, column 21.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
#{bean.adminUser ? 'Welcome Power User' userParam : bean.normalUser ? 'Welcome User' userParam :'Welcome to sytem'}
```

You can't concatenate strings in EL this way.

If you're using EL 2.2, you could use string's `concat()` method.

```
#{bean.adminUser ? 'Welcome Power User '.concat(userParam) : bean.normalUser ? 'Welcome User '.concat(userParam) : 'Welcome to sytem'}
```

Or if you're still on EL 2.1, you should prepare the complete strings beforehand by another `<ui:param>` (or `<c:set>`):

```html
<ui:param name="welcomePowerUser" value="Welcome Power User #{userParam}" />
<ui:param name="welcomeUser" value="Welcome User #{userParam}" />
...
#{bean.adminUser ? welcomePowerUser : bean.normalUser ? welcomeUser : 'Welcome to sytem'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two expressions:

```
#{bean.adminUser ? 'Welcome Power User' : 'Welcome User'}#{userParam}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's actually little bit more nested I have update the question there is a condition when we do not display the user name at all.

Comment: @JavaKaBaby You'll probably have to use whatever the JSF equivalent of `<c:if>` is. (`<h:outputText rendered="#{test}" …/>` or something.) Alternately, create the output message in your bean, or in an EL function. EL really isn't meant to be able to express complex logic to begin with.

Comment: Another option could be `<h:outputFormat …/>` where only the format is dynamic, and you supply the parameters all the formats need at once.

Comment: Thanks I have gone with approach and voted up . If no other option comes up then will accept as well . Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Oh, just realised the reason you're using EL is because you're setting `header` as an attribute. I think (not really sure though, this is based on some inconclusive Google results) that you can set complex headers in PrimeFaces by adding a `<f:facet name="header">...` into the panel, instead of using an attribute. This should let you use `<h:outputFormat/>` inside the facet.